# In Pycharm debug mode, how to step out to my code instead of steping out to library sources?

Tags: python, pycharm

In contrast to "step into", "step into my code" can skip over library sources, so is there a tool to step out to my code?

EDITED: Now I am in `forward, Transformer.py:105`, but if I click "step out", I will return to `_call_impl, module.py:727` instead of `forward, Transformer.py:132`. In other words, I need click "step out" twice to return to `forward, Transformer.py:132`. It's very inconvenient.

[image]

Comment: I think if you do step in step out, and again step in, it will go to the next function in the same line

Comment: Just keep clicking step out

Comment: Right next to the button "step into" in the debug console window, the is a button "step out" (default shortcut is shift+F8)

Comment: @QuantumMecha Is there a one-click method?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for 'skip over', that will get you line by line without entering deep into code.
Btw. "step into" is opposite to "step out", if you'll end up too deep :)

P.S.
Also, in pyCharm debug, there is 'pause play' button, that will resume program till next trigger point. Usefull

Comment: Thanks, but I don't mean 'skip over', I have updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a button for "step out into my code". However, one slight work around is to set `JustMyCode: true` in the launch config. This will only let you step line by line through your own code, and excludes external libraries.

The drawback is that if you later want to step into external library code, you will have to disable this again.

Below is a simple launch config example:

```
{
    "name": "Python: Current File",
    "type": "python",
    "request": "launch",
    "program": "${file}",
    "console": "integratedTerminal",
    "justMyCode": true
},
```